# know if application is running alpha, beta or release

Tags: android, google-play, alpha, beta

I'm starting an early alpha testing of my application and I'd like to setup a server side environment for, almost, two of them allowed: release and beta.

Notice how it works, you deploy in alpha status and then you can promote to beta so, the binary APK distro is just the same.

Is there a way to know if current running application came from alpha, beta or release so I can decide at runtime which of my REST services I should post to?

Have anybody tried this? How yo setup same package to work with diffetent server side envs?

Answer (score 0):

Why not sending Application's build number to your backend api ? That way you can know which App Build is sending those requests, and can decide whether they are alpha, beta or whatever you name it.

To check it, you can use the code below.

```
/**
 * Retrieves Version Name defined in Manifest File.
 *
 * @return
 */
 private String getVersionName() {
      PackageInfo pInfo = null;
      String versionName = "";
      try {
          pInfo = getActivity().getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getActivity().getPackageName(), 0);
            versionName = pInfo.versionName;
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            /* This never will be thrown but Don't take any Action if it happens somehow. Method will return an Empty String by Default */
        }
        return versionName;
 }
```

Comment: APK is deployed to alpha status and then promoted. Build number is embeded in the bin and won´t change after promotion. I´ve edited the question to reflect the real problem.

Comment: There is no possible solution in the way you want. It's should have been in GooglePlayServices but it's not. There are two solutions I can come up with, 1st is the build number, you can upload a new apk before deploying your app to beta or release, it's not a big deal. And the second solution is that you can check the date . You will know when you change the Deployment status and you can check it with the date.